# Parameter pack expansion in mem-initializer-list fails with expression-list

Tags: c++, c++14

I think I miss something when perusing [C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) section 12.6.2 "Initializing bases and members", but I have not been able to figure it out.  Specifically, section 12.6.2 paragraph 1 says that mem-initializer can either be mem-initializer-id(expression-list_opt) or mem-initializer-id braced-init-list, and mem-initializer... is (as far as I can see in the rest of 12.6.2) a valid construct.  But, the following program shows otherwise (which means that I miss further constraint(s) imposed on the grammar in paragraph 1):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct C1 {
  bool a;
  float b;
  C1(bool x, float y) : a(x), b(y) {}
};
struct C2 {
  bool c;
  float d;
  C2(bool x, float y) : c(x), d(y) {}
};
struct C3 {
  bool e;
  float f;
  C3(bool x, float y) : e(x), f(y) {}
};

template<class... baseclasses>
struct A : public baseclasses...
{
  template<class... Ts> A(Ts... args) : baseclasses(args...)... {
    // This uses mem-initializer-id(expression-list_opt).
    // Section 5.2 par 1 says that expression-list is initializer-list.
    // Section 8.5 par 1 says that initializer-list can be
    //     initializer-clause... with initializer-clause being
    //     assignment-expression.
    // Section 5.17 par 1 says that assignment-expression can boil down
    //     to an identifier, for example, args.
    // So, the construct is valid as far as I can see.  But,
    // g++ 5.4.1 fails with: invalid use of pack expansion expression.
    // g++ 7.2.0 fails with: no matching function for call to
    //     ‘C1::C1(bool)’.
    // The fix is to use mem-initializer-id braced-init-list as in:
    //     : baseclasses{args...}...
  }
};

int main() {
  A<C1, C2, C3> a(true, 1.0F);
  std::printf("%d %f %d %f %d %f\n", a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.e, a.f);
}
```

My question is: where specifically in the C++14 standard is it mentioned that parameter pack expansion in mem-initializer-list can only work with the second alternative of mem-initializer?  Or, is it actually okay to use the first alternative but I need some syntax trick to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: gcc bug, [compile fine on clang](https://godbolt.org/g/Ak3gTS)

Comment: @liliscent: I will check this with the GCC maintainers.  Thank you.

Comment: @liliscent I filed the question at https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2018-02/msg00105.html

Comment: @liliscent I filed the bug in GCC bugzilla at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84464